# Setting back button custom outlook doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some difficulties to set back image.. what is weird, because in different controllers it does work. Probably `self.navigationItem` is invalid, but why if I just push the `ViewController` from different `ViewController`..?

I've tried:

```
// preview buttonImage shows that image is correct and exists
UIImage *buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"back"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"TEST" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:NULL];
[buttonItem setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = buttonItem;
```

Different approach:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setTitle:@"TEST" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = buttonItem;
```

I thought that maybe self.navigationItem is wrong, but it seems to exist:

```
NSLog(@"%@, %@", self.navigationItem, self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem);
--CONSOLE-- MyApp[56574:3827402] <UINavigationItem: 0x7b6ecd10>, <UIBarButtonItem: 0x7b6f01c0>
```

I've even tried to set:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil;
```

What also doesn't seem to work.

-- edit --

However following code DOES work:

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

What suggests, that `self.navigationItem` is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ach, obviously. I forgot that for new iOS i'm setting:

```
UIImage *backImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back"];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsCompact];
```

so I need to change it for this controller, where I want to use different image.